# rewriting a query which uses case statement multiple times

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT Transaction_Id,Transaction_Amount,
Seller_Account_Number=CASE Transaction_Identifier When 'S' Then counter_Account_Number Else Account_Number END,
Seller_Name=CASE Transaction_Identifier When 'S' Then counter_Account_Name Else Account_Name END ,
Buyer_Account_Number=CASE Transaction_Identifier When 'S' Then Account_Number Else Counter_Account_Number END ,
Buyer_Name=CASE Transaction_Identifier When 'S' Then Account_Name Else Counter_Account_Name END,
FROM Transaction_Table
```

in this query i am extracting data from transaction table which has two type of transaction buy and sell with data

```
Transaction_Id    Transaction_Amount   Account_Number   Account_Name   Counter_Account_Number   Counter_Account_Name   Transaction_Identifier

123457                    200              5234545        Supriti               3476756                  Ria                    S 
123458                    300              5234545        Supriti               3476756                  Ria                    B
123459                    700              5234545        Supriti               3476756                  Ria                    S
```

and my result should be like this

```
Transaction_Id   Transaction_Amount   Seller_Account_Number   Seller_Account_Name   Buyer_Account_Number  Buyer_Name
123457                  200                  3476756                    Ria             5234545          Supriti 
123457                  700                  3476756                    Ria             5234545          Supriti 
123458                  300                  5234545                  Supriti           3476756          Ria
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Do you get an error or very slow execution times? What is the problem?

Comment: Are you requesting optimization opinions? Does your code not work? Please post example data and results.

Comment: code works fine but it is slow

Comment: Please edit your post and clearly state the question.